# import mysql database in to pspp?

Tags: mysql, database, open-source, spss

Hi friends am looking in to pspp for charting ans stastics

can anyone tell me how can i connect my mysql database in to pspp gnu .

is my mysql supported by pspp ?

this is the homwpage os pspp am using now

http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/

which is an replacement os spss

any help will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, MySQL is not currently supported by PSPP; however, PostgreSQL is. You might want to try converting your database and seeing if you have any luck with that. Check out the [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL) for some tips on how to convert from other databases to PostgreSQL.

See the entry in the [PSPP manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/manual/pspp.html#GET-DATA-_002fTYPE_003dPSQL) on how to import data from PostgreSQL in PSPP.